# Siri adds a dot in front of app name in Siri response

Tags: ios, iphone, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I made a Custom SiriKit intent and everything works fine in English but when I run the intent in another language the Siri responds like:

> .App Name dice: "Resultado en español"

Same execution in English:

> App Name says: "Result in English"

Notice the "." prefixing the app name. Siri literally says "dot" and it's pretty annoying. Anyway I can get rid of that "."?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that this only happens with some Intent categories:

- Categories failing in spanish: Search, Find, View.
- Categories OK in spanish: Run, Request

[image]

It seems to be a bug.